# Is there a api to create a picture in php

Tags: php, image

Is there a api to  create a picture in php? I want to create a chart in gif or jpg format.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[There are several](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are [several described in the manual](http://us.php.net/image).

Here's an example from the manual describing how to use [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) to create a JPEG:

```
<?php
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Skip the filename parameter using NULL, then set the quality to 75%
imagejpeg($im, NULL, 75);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create charts, maybe the [Google Chart's Api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html) or something [similar](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/adv-upload-image.php) , while not strictly php, maybe useful for you. Note that The second link doesn't create images, it creates flash charts, but they can be saved as an image.